# Using Youtube ApiV3 locally as well as on server

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am a beginner in C# so it will be helpful if you explain the issue in simple words. I have issue regarding uploading a video on my YouTube channel through server using YouTube API v3 but when I run my code locally I have no issues uploading a video.But hosting on IIS/Server gives object reference error.
Below is the code I am trying to execute for video uploading which is written on upload button.

```
protected async void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtVideoTitle.Text != "" && txtFileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        date = DateTime.Now;
        string CLIENT_ID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        string CLIENT_SECRET = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];                
        var youtubeService = AuthenticateOauth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,"singleuser");
        if (youtubeService == null) throw new  ArgumentNullException("youtubeService");
        var video = new Video();
        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = txtVideoTitle.Text;
        video.Snippet.Description = txtVideoDescription.Text;
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };                
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";
        if (video == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("video");
        var filename = txtFileUpload.FileName;
        Stream filepath = txtFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
        var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,"snippet,status", filepath, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
        await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        message.Text = "Video Uploaded Successfully!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        message.Text = "Please enter required details...";
    }
}
 public static YouTubeService AuthenticateOauth(string cLIENT_ID, string cLIENT_SECRET, string v)
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit,
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                                         YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload};

        try
        {
            // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = cLIENT_ID, ClientSecret = cLIENT_SECRET }
                                                                                         , scopes
                                                                                         , v
                                                                                         , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                         , new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;

            YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Web"
            });
            if (service == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
            return service;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the above code I have handled youtube service where it throws exception because it receives null value when I host it on server or IIS on company network.But when I run my code locally(development machine) It doesn't throw any exception.
I have spent days solving the issue but to no avail.Any help will be appreciated.
The exception message is 
Server Error in '/' Application.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: youtubeService
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: youtubeService

Comment: Add an exception message to your question.

Comment: I would check AuthenticateOauth it doesn't appear to be returning anything

Comment: I checked AuthenticateOauth and I know it doesn't return anything.When I execute the code locally/localhost it returns value but running on IIS it doesn't seems to return anything.Any idea what the issue might be

Comment: Then you will need to debug your AuthenticateOauth  method to determine why it doesn't work when running on IIS.   We would be happy to help you but you need to post enough code that someone can recreate the issue.  You know the issue is in the AuthenticateOauth method why didn't you post that?

Comment: That's the issue.I cant debug the code while it is on IIS like when you debug the code locally by putting breakpoints. On IIS I dont now how can you debug the code.I have pasted  the AuthenticateOauth code.Sorry for not posting it earlier

Comment: I think the issue comes from the fact that I cant refresh the token received from google on IIS

Comment: Getting the same issue, But its not authentication issue on my side, I am getting this exception in server, but working fine in local machine
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal    at UploadVideo.videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress progress)     at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadAsync>d__84.MoveNext()  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)**